# How to handle when OP answers with my own answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, attribution

I answered a question and provided precise steps on how to solve OP's problems. A few hours later I found out that OP answered his or her question with a fairly identical answer to mine. My instructions are more extensive, but at the core both our codes are the same.

This is the question: [Set transform from another GameObject's script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975418/unity-set-transform-from-another-gameobjects-script/23976882#23976882)

What should I do? I guess I could down vote, but I don't want to be mean. I already commented on the OP's answer. Should I just let it go?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You just move on.

Comment: I had a similar case: another answerer had a bug in his code.  I pointed it out to him and he changed his answer to use my code and it got accepted.  I flagged it and the result was a condescending snort from the moderator.  So net-net forget it and move on.

Comment: well, that's what the comments section is for when things are unclear. Before you answer just make sure youre on the same page as the OP. There are about 10-15 other checks I personally started doing before event attempting to answer just to make sure the OP is worth my time

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If it's plagiarism, then you can flag it for moderator attention (but this example, at first glance, doesn't appear to be plagiarism).

If it just happens to be an answer similar to yours, then you can probably leave it be.  Don't worry so much about getting the credit.  There will be more questions.

---

If the answer the OP posted is correct, and I don't think that he/she plagiarized me, or otherwise intentionally copied my answer, than I personally would leave it be.

Of course you can up/down vote on the answer for just about any reason that you please, so you're allowed to downvote the answer if that makes you feel better.

Comment: I'd have to agree.  I looked at both answers, and since I know zip about any of that stuff, they looked pretty different to me, even if they are actually the same answer.

Answer (score 12):

Firstly, assume innocent intent. Perhaps your phrasing is awkward, or you're too wordy, or your speaking above the OP's head, etc.. And, unless it's a copy/past job, leave open the possibility that the user's restatement may actually be *better*: It may make more sense than your "original" to other visitors in the same predicament.

Your ego aside, we want better answers. Even if they're derivatives.

If you're pretty sure they just copied your answer in an attempt to steal credit or undermine the system, go ahead and flag and/or downvote it. Probably avoid answering that user's future questions.

But, if there's some variation in the answer, the "better" answer will likely receive more votes. If yours did, don't fuss over it. Lesser answers often elevate better ones. If yours get fewer votes, maybe it wasn't clear, or it was too verbose, or was in some other way *not as good* as the OP's restatement of your answer. Figure out why and do better next time.

Secondly, don't take it personally. Don't dwell on it. Move on.

---

In your particular case, I don't sense foul play. I sense the OP really needed to work through it to understand it. That said, you still have more votes. So ... definitely just get over it.